# bi-dimensional array when joining tables in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables, `projects`:

```
+----+----------+-------+------------+
| id | name     | admin | timestamp  |
+----+----------+-------+------------+
|  1 | Group1   |     2 | 1539678214 |
|  2 | Test     |     2 | 1539678214 |
+----+----------+-------+------------+
```

And `users`:

```
+----+----------------+------------------------+
| id | name           | email                  |
+----+----------------+------------------------+
|  1 | FOO            | foo@bar.com            |
|  2 | BAR            | bar@foo.com            |
|  3 | G2W            | far@boo.com            |
+----+----------------+------------------------+
```

I run the following SQL command:

```
SELECT projects.id,projects.name,users.id as userid,users.email 
FROM projects 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id=projects.admin;
```

And I get the following result:

```
+----+----------+--------+-----------------+
| id | name     | userid | email           |
+----+----------+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | Group1   |      2 | bar@foo.com     |
|  2 | Test     |      2 | bar@foo.com     |
+----+----------+--------+-----------------+
```

And this is perfect, it's just what I need. Now my question is, what is the best way to do this in PHP and get the result in a bi-dimensional array.

This is what I have so far, but I get the result in a one-dimensional array, which i don't want:

```
$stmt = $_DB->prepare("SELECT projects.id,projects.name,users.id as userid,users.email 
                       FROM projects 
                       INNER JOIN users ON users.id=projects.admin");
if($$_DB->error) die($$_DB->error);

$stmt->execute();
$res=$stmt->get_result();
while($result[]=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){}
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Group1
        [userid] => 2
        [email] => bar@foo.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Test
        [userid] => 2
        [email] => bar@foo.com
    )
```

**This is what i want:**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Group1
        [admin] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [email] => bar@foo.com
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Test
        [admin] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [email] => bar@foo.com
            )

    )
```

Comment: There is no ready way to accomplish what you want. You'd need to write the code youself to interpret the results in whatever structure you see fit.

Comment: How does laravel do it? Don't they use a plugin or something?

Comment: The same way the framework does everything else. (E.g. interpreting query parameters.) Just by writing the appropriate code to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: @131 Laravel uses Eloquent ORM. ORM do it in PHP layer. Querying on RDBMS like MySQL will always give you a tabular format data ( array of arrays) - second level array being individual row

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answers :/

Comment: Just do a foreach to rebuild your result as you want? Or maybe (but it will be "ugly" : do a SELECT concat(...) and build a JSON format string to get your result and just do a json_decode after...but the foreach should be better !

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do it without having to implement unique code for every table you want to do this for. Like if i want nested joins or multiple joins, i have to do all this manually...

Comment: @131 You can look at Doctrine ORM, Spot ORM, RedBeans ORM, Eloquent etc, in case you don;t want to write this PHP code by yourself. They will provide you an Object representation of your relational data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query results will always be in a Tabular format (rows and columns). Basically, it will be an array of arrays, wherein second-level array represents a particular row. If you want your results to be in Multi-dimensional array, you will have to do this using PHP code, after getting query output:

```
$res=$stmt->get_result();

// Initialize result variable
$result = array();

// Get results row by row
while( $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {

    // In a temp variable, create the multi-dim array as you wish
    $temp['id'] = $row['id'];
    $temp['name'] = $row['name'];
    $temp['admin'] = array('id' => $row['userid'], 
                           'email' => $row['email']);

    // insert the temp result row
    $result[] = $temp;
}
print_r($result);
```